# Reactnative Issue

Tags: api, react-native, authentication

I have a very simple login screen where the user enters userid and password. when the user clicks on login button then flow moves to next screen if entered userid/password combination is correct.

on click of login button, I am calling an API with userid and password as input. API returns a count of matching records from DB in JSON format.If the count is >0 then login is successful.

**Issue:** I have to click login button twice. when I click on login button nothing happens but if I click it again then I get fail message or move to the second screen depending on userid/password combination. I am copying my code below. I'll appreciate any help.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  View,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';

import {
  StackNavigator 
} from 'react-navigation';

export default class Login extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      uCount: -1,
      data: []
    };
  }

   getData(){
    var url="https://myurl/verifySubscription.php?email=" + this.state.email + "&password=" + this.state.password;
    console.log("URL:", url);
    return fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
     this.setState({
      uCount: responseJson.count
    })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }

async _onPressButton() {

      await this.getData();
        console.log("uCount:", this.state.uCount);
        if (this.state.uCount < 1) {
            Alert.alert('Login Failed: Incorrect email or password')
        } else {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginSuccess', { email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password})      
        }
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.wrapper}>
          <View style={styles.topView}>
             <Image style={styles.imageStyle}
             source={require('../images/main.jpg')}
             />
          </View>         
          <View style={styles.bottomView}>
              <StatusBar
                 barStyle="light-content"
              />
              <TextInput style={styles.Input}
                placeholder="Email"
                placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
                keyBoardType='email-address'
                returnKeyType="next"
                autoCapitalize="none"
                autoCorrect={false}
                onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordInput.focus()}
                onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email:text})}
              />
              <TextInput style={styles.Input}
                placeholder="Password"
                placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
                returnKeyType="go"
                secureTextEntry
                autoCapitalize="none"
                autoCorrect={false}
                ref={(next) => this.passwordInput = next}
                onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password:text})}
              />
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button1Container} onPress={ this._onPressButton.bind(this) }>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                  Login
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button2Container}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                  Sign up
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    wrapper: {
       backgroundColor: '#4A7AA5',
       flex: 1
    },
    topView: {
        flexGrow: 1
    },
    imageStyle: {
        width: null,
        flex: 1
    },
    bottomView: {
      padding: 20
    },
    Input: {
      height:40,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.3)',
      marginBottom: 10,
      color: '#FFF',
      paddingHorizontal: 10
    },
    button1Container: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(200,200,255,0.3)',
      padding: 10
    },
    buttonText: {
      textAlign: 'center',
      color: '#FFF',
      fontWeight: '700'
    },
    button2Container: {
      padding: 10
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue maybe related to the async process when you press the button. fetch will return a promise which then can be resolve after response is completed. Try this, not using await (es2017), just es6.

```
getData(){
    var url="https://myurl/verifySubscription.php?email=" + this.state.email + 
   "&password=" + this.state.password;
    console.log("URL:", url);
    return fetch(url);
}

_onPressButton() {
    this.getData().then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
       const cnt = responseJson.cnt;

      if (cnt < 1) {
        Alert.alert('Login Failed: Incorrect email or password')
      } else {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginSuccess', { email: 
          this.state.email, password: this.state.password})      
      }
   });
}
```